# How accurate is this Google translate?

Tags: meaning

参与联合国教科文预算管理委员会

> Google translate said "UNESCO participation in the budget management committee."

Answer (score 1):

In the original Chinese sentence, `联合国教科文预算管理委员会` is an whole, which refers to the `budget management committee of UNESCO`.

And one more mistake, Google translate `参与` to `participation` ,which is of noun form. Actually, here in the Chinese sentence, `参与` is a verb, and the object is the committee.